Where is Google Client ID matched with SFMC_ID to create identified subscribers?
I am working to bring in GA360 data into SFMC to build a journey. I understand that the audience that is ultimately synced into SFMC will contain "identified subscribers" that match our audience criteria and have a Google Client ID and an SFMC ID. Where and how does the identification happen to create these identified subscribers? Does this happen in GTM?

Yes, If you purchased the Google Integration SKU within MCE, emails sent from a journey will have the SFMC_ID parameter appended to all links. Google will then consume and do this matching, Any subscriber matched will that is in a sync audience will then be imported into a DE for further engagement

Ok, so do I need to include a filter in the GA audience that I plan to sync to Marketing Cloud to filter for users with sfmc_ids or will that happen automatically? For example, I want to enter US users into a journey after they visit a specific webpage. So my GA audience would include country (USA), page title/path, but do I need to include something for sfmc_id is not null?

it will only sync matched subscribers
